# How to align image to center of Div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using PHP & smarty, I am trying to get a slideshow's images to display in the middle of the provided `div` but cannot get it done.

Below is the code, can anybody assist with what I am missing?

**Code:**

```
<div class="home_slide_show">
  <!--start-image-slider---->
    <div>                                               
      <ul class="rslides" id="slider_cars">
       {section name=sec1 loop=$car_photos}
         <li><img src="{$car_photos[sec1].photo}" alt=""></li>
       {/section}
      </ul>
    </div>
  <!--End-image-slider---->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.home_slide_show{
    background-color: white;
    border: solid thick grey;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

.home_slide_show img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: block;
}
```

**Full HTML Code:**

```
 <div class="home_slide_show">
  <!--start-image-slider---->
  <div>
    <ul class="rslides rslides2" id="slider_cars">
      <li style="vertical-align: middle; display: block; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;" id="rslides2_s0" class=""><img src="images/cars/download.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li style="vertical-align: middle; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; display: list-item; transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;" id="rslides2_s1" class=""><img src="images/cars/images (1).jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li style="vertical-align: middle; float: left; position: relative; opacity: 1; z-index: 2; display: list-item; transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;" id="rslides2_s2" class="rslides2_on"><img src="images/cars/images (2).jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li style="vertical-align: middle; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; display: list-item; transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;" id="rslides2_s3" class=""><img src="images/cars/images (7).jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li style="vertical-align: middle; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; display: list-item; transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;" id="rslides2_s4" class=""><img src="images/cars/images.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--End-image-slider---->
</div>
```

Comment: Where's `home_slide_show` class in html?

Comment: YOu seem to use a templating engine. What you need to post here is actual HTML code, like it is shown in the browser. At best you create a editable example on sites like jsfiddle.net or codepen.io

Comment: @Jai centering the `<div class="image-slider">` in the `<div class="home_slide_show">` would be the easiest I suppose? the image takes up the whole `image-slider` div.

Comment: @HerrSerker I have added the full HTML code for you

Comment: @Marcel where is the css class for `image-slider`?

Comment: @Jai the class was no longer needed. forgot to remove it. I just corrected. :)

Comment: you spelled height wrong

Answer (score 1):

The user agent adds default margins and padding to the ul element. Set to zero for both.

Comment: Can you please clarify, i have no idea what you are referring to?

Comment: Add the following to your CSS file: #slider_cars {margin:0; padding:0;}
This will result into a centered image filling the div

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to center them:

```
.img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

also take a look at this post: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/